# How to convert a String into a React Component

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I have a file **myEnternal.js** that I would like to pass as a component via **Props** from Android.

**myEnternal.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default class ExternalComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>{ /** add a component a view depending on paremeters passed into class in Props**/}</View>
        );
    }
}
```

Then in Java :

```
Bundle initialProperties = new Bundle();
initialProperties.putString("myEnternal_ComponentString", Files.toString(new File("./myEnternal.js"), Charsets.UTF_8));
```

Then possibly convert it into a **Component** and add it.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
    render() {
        var myEnternal_Component = this.props.myEnternal_ComponentString;

        return (
            <View>{ /** convert myEnternal_Component into a component then add <ExternalComponent /> here **/}</View>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I go about converting a String representation of a component into a Component dynamically?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myEnternal_Component = eval(this.props.myEnternal_ComponentString);
```

Though I wouldn't recommend using `eval`